# Not able to connect to nodeJS socket.io server on localHost using flutter client

Tags: node.js, flutter, websocket, socket.io

i'm trying to stabilish a connection between a nodeJS server and a flutter app but I always receive connect_error on client side. If I try to connect by the browser, it's successful, so i think the problem is on client side.

My nodeJS server:

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', (client) => {  
    console.log('a user connected')

    client.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('Message received --> ', data)

        // io.emit('chat', data)
    })
})

http.listen(5000, () => {  
    console.log('Listening on port 5000')
})
```

Client side is implemented using [socket_io_client package](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) on InitState as follows:

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

IO.Socket socket;
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    //on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx i'm inserting my local ip address
    socket = IO.io('http//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket']
    });

    socket.connect();
    socket.on("connect", (_) => print('Connected'));
    socket.on("connect_error", (data) => print('connect_error: ' + data));

    super.initState();
  }
```

The client keeps showing the output "connect_error: timeout".

Anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Edit1: Also tried to disable windows firewall but it didn't help.

Comment: Just use `http://localhost:portnumber` or `127.0.0.1:portnumber`, you local ip is not directly available like that I am guessing.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error and I think that accessing my local IP is ok since both my pc and cellphone are in the same network. I tried to access local_ip:port over the cellphone navigator and got no problem.

Comment: That's different Lucas, just return some random text on some get call and see if you can access that on your phone.